# Solve linear system in Python without NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jython, linear-algebra

I have to solve linear equations system using Jython, so I can't use Num(Sci)Py for this purpose. What are the good alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good NumPy clone for Jython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316410/is-there-a-good-numpy-clone-for-jython)

Comment: mpmath (included in SymPy) is a pure-Python arbitrary-precision/symbolic-math library and works well in Jython. For your linear solver needs, it can invert your matrix or find its LU decomposition. See http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/matrices.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @talonmies' comment, the real answer to this is 'find an equivalent Java package.'