# How to call a java function from python/numpy?

Tags: java, numpy

it is clear to me how to extend Python with C++, but what if I want to write a function in Java to be used with numpy?

Here is a simple scenario: I want to compute the average of a numpy array using a Java class. How do I pass the numpy vector to the Java class and gather the result?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at [is-there-a-good-numpy-clone-for-jython](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316410/776084)

Comment: well, I am not really looking for a clone, as I have quite some numpy code and I find numpy very good. It is a pitty there is no direct way to use numpy with Java...

Comment: Is the Java code base significant enough in size that it would preclude you from just re-writing the performance sensitive sections in Cython and use numpy/python for the rest?

Comment: it is more a strategic decision, I do not have lot's of Java code right now. A lot of people use C++ for scientific computing, but I have the feeling that Java might replace C++ for this in the future. So ideally python/numpy should be able to use both C++ and Java classes (like matlab). If garbage collection is really a problem one would extend python with C++ otherwise Java would be better

Comment: I haven't seen any trend toward widespread adoption of Java in the scientific community, and given that it sounds like you don't have a lot of code to convert, it is probably best to use established tools like Cython, rather than treading into uncharted and unsupported waters with Java. The strategic decision is more likely the pragmatic one for using the technologies that are available today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I spent some time on my own question and would like to share my answer as I feel there is not much information on this topic on *stackoverflow*. I also think Java will become more relevant in scientific computing (e.g. see WEKA package for data mining) because of the improvement of performance and other good software development features of Java.

---

*In general, it turns out that using the right tools it is much easier to extend Python with Java than with C/C++!*

---

## Overview and assessment of tools to call Java from Python

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JCC: because of no proper
  documentation this tool is useless.
- Py4J: requires to start the Java process before using python. As
  remarked by others this is a possible point of failure. Moreover, not many examples of use are documented.
- [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/): although development seems to be death, it works well and there are
  many examples on it on the web (e.g. see http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/weka-python/ for using data mining libraries written in Java) . Therefore *I decided to focus
  on this tool*.

## Installing JPype on Fedora 16

I am using Fedora 16, since there are some issues when installing JPype on Linux, I describe my approach.
Download [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), then modify *setup.py* script by providing the JDK path, in line 48:

```
self.javaHome = '/usr/java/default'
```

then run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Afters successful installation, check this file:

*/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_linux.py*

and remove or rename the method *getDefaultJVMPath()* into *getDefaultJVMPath_old()*, then add the following method:

```
def getDefaultJVMPath():
    return "/usr/java/default/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so"
```

**Alternative approach**: do not make any change in the above file *_linux.py*, but never use the method getDefaultJVMPath() (or methods which call this method). At the place of using *getDefaultJVMPath()* provide directly the path to the JVM. Note that there are several paths, for example in my system I also have the following paths, referring to different versions of the JVM (it is not clear to me whether the client or server JVM is better suited):

- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/lib/x86_64/client/libjvm.so
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/lib/x86_64/server/libjvm.so
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so

Finally, add the following line to *~/.bashrc* (or run it each time before opening a python interpreter):

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/java/default'
```

(The above directory is in reality just a symbolic link to my last version of JDK, which is located at */usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04*).

Note that all the tests in the directory where JPype has been downloaded, i.e. *JPype-0.5.4.2/test/testsuite.py* will fail (so do not care about them).

To see if it works, test this script in python:

```
import jpype 
jvmPath = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath() 
jpype.startJVM(jvmPath)
# print a random text using a Java class
jpype.java.lang.System.out.println ('Berlusconi likes women') 
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

## Calling Java classes from Java also using Numpy

Let's start implementing a Java class containing some functions which I want to apply to *numpy arrays*. Since there is no concept of state, I use static functions so that I do not need to create any Java object (creating Java objects would not change anything).

```
/**
 * Cookbook to pass numpy arrays to Java via Jpype
 * @author Mannaggia
 */

package test.java;

public class Average2 {

public static double compute_average(double[] the_array){
    // compute the average
    double result=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<the_array.length;i++){
        result=result+the_array[i];
    }
    return result/the_array.length;
}
// multiplies array by a scalar
public static double[] multiply(double[] the_array, double factor) {

    int i;
    double[] the_result= new double[the_array.length];
    for (i=0;i<the_array.length;i++) {
        the_result[i]=the_array[i]*factor;
    }
    return the_result;
}

/**
 * Matrix multiplication. 
 */
public static double[][] mult_mat(double[][] mat1, double[][] mat2){
    // find sizes
    int n1=mat1.length;
    int n2=mat2.length;
    int m1=mat1[0].length;
    int m2=mat2[0].length;
    // check that we can multiply
    if (n2 !=m1) {
        //System.err.println("Error: The number of columns of the first argument must equal the number of rows of the second");
        //return null;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: The number of columns of the first argument must equal the number of rows of the second");
    }
    // if we can, then multiply
    double[][] the_results=new double[n1][m2];
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<n1;i++){
        for (j=0;j<m2;j++){
            // initialize
            the_results[i][j]=0;
            for (k=0;k<m1;k++) {
                the_results[i][j]=the_results[i][j]+mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return the_results;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test case
    double an_array[]={1.0, 2.0,3.0,4.0};
    double res=Average2.compute_average(an_array);
    System.out.println("Average is =" + res);
}
}
```

The name of the class is a bit misleading, as we do not only aim at computing the average of a numpy vector (using the method *compute_average*), but also multiply a numpy vector by a scalar (method *multiply*), and finally, the matrix multiplication (method *mult_mat*).

After compiling the above Java class we can now run the following Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import jpype

jvmPath = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath() 
# we to specify the classpath used by the JVM
classpath='/home/mannaggia/workspace/TestJava/bin'
jpype.startJVM(jvmPath,'-Djava.class.path=%s' % classpath)

# numpy array
the_array=np.array([1.1, 2.3, 4, 6,7])
# build a JArray, not that we need to specify the Java double type using the jpype.JDouble wrapper
the_jarray2=jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, the_array.ndim)(the_array.tolist())
Class_average2=testPkg.Average2 
res2=Class_average2.compute_average(the_jarray2)
np.abs(np.average(the_array)-res2) # ok perfect match! 

# now try to multiply an array
res3=Class_average2.multiply(the_jarray2,jpype.JDouble(3))
# convert to numpy array
res4=np.array(res3) #ok

# matrix multiplication
the_mat1=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],dtype=float)
#the_mat2=np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]],dtype=float)
the_mat2=np.array([[1], [1], [1]],dtype=float)
the_mat3=np.array([[1, 2, 3]],dtype=float)

the_jmat1=jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, the_mat1.ndim)(the_mat1.tolist())
the_jmat2=jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, the_mat2.ndim)(the_mat2.tolist())
res5=Class_average2.mult_mat(the_jmat1,the_jmat2)
res6=np.array(res5) #ok

# other test
the_jmat3=jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, the_mat3.ndim)(the_mat3.tolist())
res7=Class_average2.mult_mat(the_jmat3,the_jmat2)
res8=np.array(res7)
res9=Class_average2.mult_mat(the_jmat2,the_jmat3)
res10=np.array(res9)

# test error due to invalid matrix multiplication
the_mat4=np.array([[1], [2]],dtype=float)
the_jmat4=jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble, the_mat4.ndim)(the_mat4.tolist())
res11=Class_average2.mult_mat(the_jmat1,the_jmat4)

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println ('Goodbye!') 
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Answer (score 2):

I consider Jython to be one of the best options - which makes it seamless to use java objects in python. I actually integrated weka with my python programs, and it was super easy. Just import the weka classes and call them as you would in java within the python code.

http://www.jython.org/

Comment: yes, I know. But the problem with jython is that unfortunately it does not support numpy as well as many other python libraries for scientific computing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about numpy support, but the following might be helpful:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JCC/

Comment: it might be helpful, but I was hoping in some step-by-step instructions using some higher level wrapper. In theory one should 1) call java from C++, and then 2) call C++ from python.

Comment: in addition, the documentation of JCC is horrible (or should I say absent?), I did not get any clue on how to use it...